# Keep getting a certain error with tkinter root.destroy

Tags: python, tkinter, destroy

I have been having lots of problems with this code, it is giving me a weird error. It occurs when I attempt to close the program; I get this error(shown at the bottom ). I also previously before adding the .protocol but was getting an error to do with the module. Is it the way I have imported tkinter? Or what I am attempting to destroy?

```
    import tkinter.ttk
    from tkinter.constants import *
    from tkinter import *
    class App(ttk.Frame):

        @classmethod
        def main(cls):
            GUI = tkinter.Tk()
            app = cls(GUI)
            app.grid(sticky=NSEW)
            GUI.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            GUI.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            GUI.resizable(True, False)
            GUI.mainloop()
            self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy())
            GUI.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", GUI.destroy())

        def __init__(self, GUI):
            super().__init__(GUI)
            self.create_variables()
            self.create_widgets()
            self.grid_widgets()
            self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        def create_variables(self):
            pass

        def create_widgets(self):
            self.Logo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="Logo.gif")
            self.x = Label(image=self.Logo)
            ##Top bar Widgets##
            self.button1 =ttk.Button(self, text="Profile", command=self.GetProfile)
            if self.CheckLogin() == False:
                self.button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Log in", command=self.Login)
            self.button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Download",command=self.download)
            self.Label2 = ttk.Label(self,text="")
        def grid_widgets(self):
            options = dict(sticky=NSEW, padx=3, pady=4)
            options1 = dict(sticky=N)
            self.x.grid(column=0,row=1, **options1)
            #top bar
            self.button1.grid(column = 1,row = 1,**options1)
            self.button2.grid(column = 2,row = 1,**options1)
            self.button3.grid(column = 3,row = 1,**options1)

        #To be completed functions
        def download(self):
            pass
        def GetProfile(self):
            pass

        def Login(self):
            if self.Logindefault() == True:
                print("login here")
            elif self.Logindefault() == False:
                self.v = StringVar()
                print("Not logged in.")
                options = dict(sticky=NSEW, padx=3, pady=4)
                self.t = Toplevel(self)
                self.t.title("Login")
                self.t.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
                self.t.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
                self.t.entry1 = ttk.Entry(self.t)
                self.t.entry2 = ttk.Entry(self.t)
                self.t.button1 = ttk.Button(self.t,text="login",command=self.destroy)
                self.t.entry1.grid(column = 0 ,row = 0, **options)
                self.t.entry1.insert(0,"Username")
                self.t.entry2.grid(column = 0 ,row = 1, **options)
                self.t.entry2.insert(0,"Password")
                self.t.button1.grid(column = 1,row = 0,rowspan=2, **options)
                self.t.checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(self.t,text="Remember me",variable=self.v)
                self.t.checkbox.grid(column =0,row=2,**options)

        def destroy(self):
            self.usernameGO = self.t.entry1.get()
            self.passwordGO = self.t.entry2.get()
            print(self.usernameGO,self.passwordGO,self.v)
            self.t.destroy()
        def CheckLogin(self):
            return False #If not logged in.
        def Logindefault(self):
            try:
                file = open("UserLog.txt","rt")
                for i in file:
                    if i[0:6] =="__usr__":
                        self.username = i.sptrip("__usr__")

                    elif i[0:6] =="__pss__":
                        self.password = i.strip("__pss__")
                return True
            except Exception:
                #username file not found
                print("error")
                return False





    if __name__ == '__main__':
        App.main()
```

Here is the error which I get when I try to close the main window:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in destroy
    for c in list(self.children.values()): c.destroy()
  File "C:\Users\charlie\Desktop\Yahtzee - Copy.py", line 74, in destroy
    self.usernameGO = self.t.entry1.get()
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 't'
```

Comment: Well, `self.t` gets created during the `Login` function. Are you calling that function before you close the window?

Answer (score 1):

```
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy())
        GUI.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", GUI.destroy())
```

Generally, when you register callback methods, you need to omit the parentheses. Otherwise, the methods will be called immediately, and their return values will be registered instead. This means that `destroy` will be executed before `Login` executes, so `self.t` won't yet exist. Try:

```
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy)
        GUI.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", GUI.destroy)
```

Comment: Thanks I will get onto making these adjustments and I see now how the parentheses could have been the problem